# Can you tweak an Angular component to use different values every time you use it?

Tags: angular, components

I have a component like this:

```
<ice-cream-cone></ice-cream-cone>
<ice-cream-cone></ice-cream-cone>
<ice-cream-cone></ice-cream-cone>
```

The problem is that the component calls above will result in them all looking the exact same. Can you tweak the directive to trigger the loading of specific values in the component? I'm hoping for something along the lines of this:

```
<ice-cream-cone flavor="vanilla"></ice-cream-cone>
<ice-cream-cone flavor="chocolate"></ice-cream-cone>
<ice-cream-cone flavor="rocky_road"></ice-cream-cone>
```

Comment: Sure you can... That's the basic of angular component with `@Input()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, this can be done using the Input binding property
Something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ice-cream-cone',
  template: `
    {{flavor}}
  `
})
class IceCreamComponent {
  @Input('flavor') flavor: string;
}
```

And then when you call the component, you would the following:

```
<ice-cream-cone flavor="vanilla"></ice-cream-cone>
```

Check it out here: [Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for.